# Laravel: Send e-mail via imap server on Vapor

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-vapor

I'm trying to send a email from my Laravel app. Everything works fine on my local server, but when I deploy the app to Vapor I get a 503 error.

I'm using a regular IMAP/SMTP server for sending the e-mail and I have updated the .env file on Vapor with correct mail server settings.

Why won't Vapor send my e-mail?

`vapor env:pull staging`

```
APP_NAME=AppName
APP_KEY=base64:(removed)
APP_DEBUG=false

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.domeneshop.no
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=(removed)
MAIL_PASSWORD=(removed)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=(removed)
MAIL_FROM_NAME=AppName
```

Comment: what is the 500 error message?

Comment: My bad. It's a 503 error.
By the looks of this I can't use a different smtp server. Correct?
```
Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503-All RCPT commands were
rejected with this error:
503-sender IP address 13.49.49.242 is part of Amazon AWS, and may not use this
503-server as a smarthost. Amazon servers should use Amazon SES
503-(https://aws.amazon.com/ses/)
```